# How to apply materialize css in blogger?

Tags: blogger, materialize

I want to apply an effect and controls of "materializecss" to my blog.
Currently I am using simple blogger template provided by blogger.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What is materialize.css? A file? a program? A website?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Its a UI Component library created with HTML, CSS and JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Well, what have you tried? And I'm not sure what library means unfortunately. So if you can tell me more about how it's usually accessed, that'd help.

Comment: i tried it in other way..

Comment: i used materialize css in my other project.. its design and created by google. Google's goal is to develop a system of design that allows for a unified user experience across all their products on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

Just attach following cdn to your blog.

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

to know how to apply css in blog read this...

https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

```
1. goto: open cdnjs.com (or other cdn),
search materialize, (click appropriate result)
hover url with suffix "*.min.css" (e.g: materialize.min.css)
on right, click dropdown button [copy], click [copy link tag]

2. goto: Blogger -> Template -> edit HTML.
click on code-editor -> ctrl+f (find): close-tag "</head>"

paste, copied text from cdn-site, before close-tag "</head>"

3. save. refrash blogger
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add custom CSS to your blog:

- Sign in to Blogger.
- Select the blog to update.
- In the left menu, click Template.
- Under Live on blog, click Customize.
- In the left menu, select Advanced > Add CSS.
- Add your code (copy and paste the CSS from the materialize.css file).
- On the top right, click Apply to blog.

> [Link to Google Article](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/176245?hl=en)